# go/docker : Cannot burn value to binary executable using -X linker flag when using docker compose

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, dockerfile, linker-flags

I can't seem to figure out how to provide a build time variable using the docker-compose file. I have done quite a bit of research and still can't figure the way out. What I'm trying to do is to burn my latest commit hash as a value to the version variable in my binary executable which is used by my server. I'm using windows as a side note. Here's my dockerfile

```
# Build Stage
FROM golang:1.18-alpine3.16 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
ARG VERSION
ENV VERSION=$VERSION
RUN GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags='-s -X main.version=$VERSION' -o main 
./cmd/api
RUN apk add curl
RUN curl -L https://github.com/golang- 
migrate/migrate/releases/download/v4.15.2/migrate.linux-amd64.tar.gz | tar xvz

# Run Stage
FROM alpine:3.16
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/main .
COPY --from=builder /app/migrate ./migrate
COPY app.env .
COPY start.sh .
COPY wait-for.sh .
COPY /migrations ./migration

EXPOSE 3001
CMD [ "/app/main" ]
ENTRYPOINT [ "/app/start.sh" ]
```

The version variable should be having my latest commit hash. Here's my docker-compose file

```
version: "3.9"
services:
 postgres:
  build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: db.dockerfile
  environment:
   - POSTGRES_USER=root
   - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret
   - POSTGRES_DB=blogpost
  ports:
    - "542:5432"
 api:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    args:
    - VERSION=git describe --always --dirty    <<< Trying to pass value here
  ports:
   - "3001:3001"
  environment:
   - DB_DSN=postgres://root:secret@postgres:5432/blogpost?sslmode=disable
  depends_on:
   - postgres
  entrypoint: [ "/app/wait-for.sh", "postgres:5432", "--", "/app/start.sh" ]
  command: [ "/app/main" ]
```

I have tried this too

```
args:
 - VERSION=$$(shell git describe --always --dirty)
```

In the end, the value for my version variable ends up being "$VERSION". Please guide me on this

Comment: It should help to use double and not single quotes in the argument `-ldflags="-s -X main.version=$VERSION"`.  You'll also run into some trouble since Compose can't run commands to perform variable expansions, and you're probably excluding the `.git` directory from the image build context; you'd have to find the commit hash at a higher level still.

Comment: @DavidMaze Tsym! It fixes the main issue of value not being passed. Yes you are right, I have to figure out a way, especially as I can't export environment variables in windows tho